# How can I avoid having one interface implementation require more information than another?

Tags: c++, interface

I have a C++ application that reads data from SQLite database files.  I have a class for each table in the files, and I have a classes that wrap database entities, including SQLiteDirectDatabase, SQLiteDirectTable and SQLiteDirectField.  When data is to be processed, a method in SQLiteDirectTable calls sqlite3_prepare() and sqlite3_step() as required to retrieve the data.  If an error occurs, sqlite3_errcode() and sqlite_errmsg16() are called to populate an instance of a custom exception class, and that exception is thrown to the caller.  The error functions require the database connection as an argument.  Therefore, the SQLiteDirectTable constructor includes a pointer to the database connection.

I want to extend this application to work with other types of databases, such as PostgreSQL and SQL Server.  So, I am creating interface classes, including IDirectTable. I want to be able to plug in any set of database classes without changing the calling code.  But implementations of IDirectTable for other types of databases will not need the database connection for error handling (or any other reason).   Do I need to have an IDirectDatabase pointer as an argument for all IDirectTable implementations just because one implementation requires this, or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can make it a default parameter set to `nullptr`. That's what I often do. Or, can you possibly pass the DB pointer to a constructor of the child class which needs it?

Comment: Instead of adding polymorphism to the API level, I'd suggest adding polymorphism in the lowest level possible to actually implement your classes. That way, the acual API don't have much abstract-ness, but the implementation deal with the abstract-ness.

Comment: To answer ChrisMM's question, I was thinking I didn't want a calling program to have to know to pass a DB pointer to an instance of one class but not to an instance of another.  The caller shouldn't need to care about what implementation it has.  But thinking this through more, I realized that I will have to set up queries in all IDirectTable implementations, and that will always require a database object, so my original question becomes moot.   I deleted it, but since it has already received comments, I undeleted it in case it ever interests anyone else.

Comment: Who hands out `IDirectTable`s? is it not `IDirectDatabase` or something that would have one?